# Regex javascript para password

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo que generar un patrón para una contraseña. He estado utilizando https://regexper.com/ para verificar mi patrón pero no consigo que cumpla con los requisitos que me piden:

- Al menos 8 caracteres. 12 máximo.
- Caracteres alfabéticos (al menos dos).
- Una mayúscula al menos.
- Puede contener de 1 a 3 dígitos. No se puede superar este límite. No tienen por qué ser consecutivos los dígitos.
- Debe contener "." o  "," o  "-".

Este seria mi regex, pero como digo no consigo hacer que funcione correctamente.

```
^((?=.*[a-záéíóúüñA-ZÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]{2,})(?=.*[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]+)(^(?=(?:\D*\d){1,3}$))(?=.*[.|,|-])){8,12}$
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Creo que no es completamente necesario hacer un Regex entero para eso. Lo que puedes hacer es contar los caracteres en un if(string.length <= 12) {} Y así con lo demás como los caracteres alfabéticos https://parzibyte.me/blog/2019/10/03/javascript-saber-caracter-letra/ aunque eso no es muy necesario, lo que se pide la mayoría de veces son solo una mayuscula un caractere especial como @ y cosas así y con un indexOf() puedes saber lo de los puntos o guiones metiendo en if()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Aquí te dejo una muestra de código en partes para que veas que RegEx te delimita cada una de tus condiciones, sólo es cuestión de que lo juntes

```
var password = "J-1a_2/.b 3c";

var numDigitos = (password.match(/\d/g) || []).length;
var numAlfabeticos = ((password.match(/\D/g) || []).length) - ((password.match(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g) || []).length);
var numEspeciales = ((password.match(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g) || []).length);
var numMayusculas = ((password.match(/[A-Z]/g) || []).length);
var numPuntoOGuion = ((password.match(/[.-]/g) || []).length);

console.log('numeros: '+ numDigitos);
console.log('alfabeticos: '+ numAlfabeticos);
console.log('mayusculas: '+ numMayusculas);
console.log('especiales: '+ numEspeciales);
console.log('longitud: '+ password.length);
console.log('punto o guion: '+ numPuntoOGuion);
```